# resize with custom allocator

Tags: c++, containers, std

How can I resize a std::vector by using a custom allocator and not the copy constructor?

Here is what I tried:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
  A(int x){
    std::cout<<" new a:"<<this<<" "<< x<<std::endl;
  }
};

template<typename T>
class ParamAlloc:public std::allocator<T>{
public:
  template<typename U> struct rebind {typedef ParamAlloc other;};

  void construct(typename std::allocator<T>::pointer p, typename std::allocator<T>::const_reference val){
    new ((void*)p) T(47);
  }


  void destroy(typename std::allocator<T>::pointer p){
    ((T*)p)->~T();
  }
};


int main(){

  ParamAlloc<A> all;
  std::vector<A,ParamAlloc<A> > ac(all);
  ac.resize(5);
}
```

but still I get compilation errors due to the compile trying to instantiate A::A().

Related to this question, what would be the best way (pre-C++11) to allocate a vector of objects of class A, where A's constuctor takes a parameter, but the A objects should not be copy constructed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pre-C++11 the `resize` member is defined as:

```
resize(size_type n, const T& = T());
```

So when you call it as `ac.resize(5)` that actually means `ac.resize(5, A())` which obviously needs a default constructor. The only workaround for C++03 is to provide an object to copy: `ac.resize(5, A(99))`, which says to resize the vector and construct any new elements as copies of `A(99)`. The copies will be done by your custom allocator, which will actually construct them as `A(47)` instead of using the copy constructor.

The requirements for `resize()` have been relaxed for C++11 and the C++11 standard says in [vector.capacity] that `vector::resize()`

> *Requires:* `T` shall be `MoveInsertable` and `DefaultInsertable` into `*this`.

`DefaultInsertable` requires that this is valid:

```
allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p)
```

That call will try to call `m.construct(p)` on the allocator `m` if that is valid, but because your allocator does not support that it will do:

```
 ::new((void *)p) T()
```

which requires a default constructor.

If you want your custom allocator to be used for `resize` you need to provide a `construct` member that can be called with just one argument e.g.

```
void construct(typename std::allocator<T>::pointer p){
  new ((void*)p) T(47);
}
```

That should mean there is no need for a default constructor when resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Just offer a default para for `A(int x)`, the complie will pass.

```
class A{
public:
  A(int x=0){//here !! 
    std::cout<<" new a:"<<this<<" "<< x<<std::endl;
  }
};
```

And the result is :

```
 new a:0x7fffe01aab5f 0
 new a:0x1c7d010 47
 new a:0x1c7d011 47
 new a:0x1c7d012 47
 new a:0x1c7d013 47
 new a:0x1c7d014 47
```

Comment: In this toy example you can do this, in other cases (where the parameter is really needed at construction time) no.

Answer (score 0):

C++ standard defines certain requirements for item type for given containers.
For instance to be storable in vector in pre-C++11 [T must meet the requirements of CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). For resize to be available [T must meet the requirements of DefaultConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize). So, what you try to achieve is explicitly prohibited by pre-C++11 standard. Maybe you it would be enough for you to use `vector::reserve` instead of `vector::resize` or you just need a different container. It is possible in C++11 though - see answer by Jonathan Wakely.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely, you are right. I somehow thought he is interested in pre C++11 behavior though. Corrected my answer to prevent confusion.